# Is there a way to make a infinite scroll for GridView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview, pagination, infinite-scroll

Can I add a `CircularProgressIndicator()` to the end of the GridView every time the bool `isLoadingPosts` is true?

```
Widget imagePostsWidget = imagePosts != null
          ? GridView.builder(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              controller: ProfileScreen.scrollController,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
              gridDelegate:
                  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
              itemCount: imagePosts.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => PostCard(
                imagePost: imagePosts[index],
                imageUrl: imagePosts[index].imageUrl,
              ),
            )
          : SizedBox();
```

This is my code currently for fetching the posts with infinite scroll. The only thing I need is an `CircularProgressIndicator()`added to the end of the GridView, but I just cant figure out a way to achieve that.

---

I want to have something like this:

```
Widget imagePostsWidget = imagePosts != null
          ? GridView.builder(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              controller: ProfileScreen.scrollController,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
              gridDelegate:
                  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
              itemCount: imagePosts.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => PostCard(
                imagePost: imagePosts[index],
                imageUrl: imagePosts[index].imageUrl,
              ),
              if(isLoadingPosts) {
                return CirularProgressIndicator();
              }
            )
          : SizedBox();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
you can achieve, Please check the below is code. Please try that code and inform me, is it works for you?

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  bool isLoadingPosts = false;
  List<ImagePost> imagePosts = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Add a listener to the scroll controller to detect when the user has reached the end of the list
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        // The user has reached the end of the list, so load more posts
        _loadMorePosts();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose the scroll controller when the widget is removed from the widget tree
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      controller: _scrollController,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
      itemCount: imagePosts.length + (isLoadingPosts ? 1 : 0), // Add 1 item for the progress indicator if isLoadingPosts is true
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if (index < imagePosts.length) {
          return PostCard(
            imagePost: imagePosts[index],
            imageUrl: imagePosts[index].imageUrl,
          );
        } else {
          // Return the progress indicator at the end of the list if isLoadingPosts is true
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }

  // Load more posts
  void _loadMorePosts() async {
    if (!isLoadingPosts) {
      setState(() {
        isLoadingPosts = true;
      });

      // Load more posts here

      setState(() {
        isLoadingPosts = false;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

In the above code, We have used the `ScrollController` That Listens for when the user reaches at the end of the list. When the user reaches at the end of the list, we set the `isLoadingPosts` flag to true and load more. we show the `CircularProgressIndicator`  at the end of the list/post. we set the `isLoadingPosts` false to update the widget tree to show the new post

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
  ListView(
    children: [
      GridView.builder(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        controller: ProfileScreen.scrollController,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3),
        itemCount: imagePosts.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => PostCard(
          imagePost: imagePosts[index],
          imageUrl: imagePosts[index].imageUrl,
        ),
      ),
      AnimatedSwitcher(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        child: isLoadingPosts
            ? Container(
                height: 72,
                child:
                    const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              )
            : const SizedBox(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```